# Find all tickets in current sprint not belonging to a specific epic

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way in ADO (Azure DevOps) to query for all work items that are in the current sprint and that are not descendents of a specific epic?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in ADO (Azure DevOps) to query for all work items that are in the current sprint and that are not descendents of a specific epic?

I am afraid there is no such way to query for work items that are not descendents of a specific epic.

As we know, we could use the [filter work items and direct links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies)：

[image]

For your situation, we could only select **Only return items that do not have matching links with parent link types**. But we could not specify a specific epic.